# Handling SQL Azure database copies

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

I am writing a service that creates a copy of a certain SQL Azure db every once in a while by issuing this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [copy] AS COPY OF [original]
```

I then periodically check the sys.dm_database_copies table to see if the copy is done. Basically, if the dm_database_copies entry is not there, it's done copying.

What concerns me is the following:
What if the copy failed? Does the dm_database_copies entry get deleted? 
My feeling is that is should not get deleted, as it contains info about the error,
but I can't be sure, because I've actually never had a db copy fail.

So the bottom line question is: does the dm_database_copies entry for a particular database id get deleted on anything else than a successful copy?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had failures in copying large databases (> 100 GB) and the record is not deleted.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951634.aspx) I read that:

> When the database copy completes successfully and the new database
> becomes ONLINE, the row in the sys.dm_database_copies view is removed
> automatically.

So it implicitly state that if the copy process fails the row is not deleted, according also to my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for confirming it by experience.